# How to create stub data for user login data

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I was trying to create stub data for the `UserDetailsService`.

So I created one spy obj and I was using in the provider as well.

Here is my code

```
beforeEach(async (() => {
  const mockUserDetailService = jasmine.createSpyObj('UserDetailsService',
    ['getUserRolePrivilegesByScreen']);
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule, MatDialogModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, RouterTestingModule, 
        MatMenuModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatPaginatorModule, MatTableModule, 
        MatSortModule, MatIconModule, MatCardModule
      ],
      declarations: [DashboardComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: DataService, useValue: spyDataService },
        { provide: UserDetailsService, useValue: mockUserDetailService},
        { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} },
        { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} },
        { provide: LayoutUtilsService, useValue: {} }
      ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    })
    .compileComponents();
}));
```

I'm getting this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'canRead' of undefined

Here is my `ts` code this there in under `ngOnInit`

```
this.dataService.setNumber(null);
if (this.userdetailservice.getUserHighestRole() == null) {
  this.router.navigateByUrl('login');
} else {
  this.screenPrivilege = this.userdetailservice.getUserRolePrivilegesByScreen('D&B');
  this.userRole = this.userdetailservice.getUserHighestRole();

  if (this.userRole == 'Fin' || this.userRole == 'Super') {
    this.columnToDisplay = [...this.Fin];
    this.landingPage = 'Fin';
    this.exportHeaders = ['No', 'Numb', 'Amout', 'Date', 'Salary', 'Status'];
  } else if (this.userRole == 'Gen') {
    this.columnToDisplay = [...this.Gen];
    this.landingPage = 'Gen';
    this.exportHeaders = ['No', 'Numb', 'Amout', 'Date', 'Salary', 'Status'];
  } else {
    this.landingPage = 'Admin';
    this.columnToDisplay = [...this.Admin];        
    this.exportHeaders = ['No', 'Numb', 'Amout', 'Date', 'Salary', 'Status'];
  }

  if (this.screenPrivilege.canRead == 'Y') {
    this.loadData();
    this.loadPeriod();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the snippet you have provided, it seems you have created a mock variable:

```
const mockUserDetailService = jasmine.createSpyObj(...);
```

But the mock is not returning anything. Perhaps something like this:

```
mockUserDetailService.getUserRolePrivilegesByScreen.and.returnValue({canRead: 'Y'});
```